# Spring Boot Web- Set FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false in Jackson

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-boot

I have read Spring boot doc (http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/docs/howto.html#message.converters ) and its mentioned that if you provide your own JacksonConvertor, it will override the default one. But I guess its not working with the below code.

What I want to do is to set DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES of the object mapper to false.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.hjh")
@Configuration
public class App {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConvertor(){
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter convertor= new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        convertor.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return convertor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ctx =   SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

    }
```

**Could any one please point out what am i doing wrong here? As it keeps on trying to bind the unknown prop from the request. If I remove the unknown prop, it all goes well**

Comment: What version of Boot is this (I recommend upgrading to the latest snapshot)? Also please post a stack trace or we don't really know what went wrong.

Comment: Upgrading the version to 0.5.0.M7 from 0.5.0.M6. Everything works as expected. Thanks Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend upgrading to the latest snapshot. "1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT" is the new latest (RC1 to follow later today hopefully).

Comment: Can I know about the timeline for the final release schedule as well?

Comment: Normally we'd expect to have 1 or 2 release candidates separated by a week or two each, then a final release. Could be more and could be longer. It all depends on how many issues are reported.

Answer (score 26):

Starting from Spring Boot 1.2.0.RC2 `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` is set to `false` by default. It can be turned back on by adding property to `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
```

Comment: I tried making this change to my Spring Boot application (1.1.9 RELEASE) and it didn't change the behavior. Adding the Primary Bean to my Configuration class (as shown in the OPs posting), however, did fix my problem

Comment: Same here. I have a unit tests that expects a 400 error when POSTing to a rest endpoint with a field that it doesn't recognize. When upgrading my app from Spring Boot 1.2.0.M2 to 1.2.0.RC2, this test starts to fail. Adding the property spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true to application.properties also has absolutely no effect.

Comment: i have found that setting the "spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties" or any other jackson property via the spring config file "application.properties" will only affect the ObjectMapper if it was defined as a Bean. So if you are creating your own object mapper via e.g., "new  ObjectMapper()" then the properties will have no effect.