# Jackson deserialisation NOT failing on unknown properties

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

Deserialisation should fail for the following POJO if the json has an additional field, as the Jackson documentation says `FAIL_ON_UKNOWN_PROPERTIES` is set by default.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@FieldNameConstants
@ToString
@Builder
@Document(collection = "form_layouts")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Jacksonized
public class MyFormLayout extends AuditableDocument {

    @NotNull
    private Boolean selected;
    @NotNull
    private Boolean disabled;
    @NotEmpty
    private List<Layout> layout;

    @NotBlank
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String realmId;
}
```

I was expecting this test to fail with `UnrecognizedPropertyException` which it doesn't even after setting this property on Jackson

```
@SpringJUnitConfig
@TestPropertySource(
        properties = {
                "spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true"
        }
)
@AutoConfigureJson
@DisplayName("Form Layout Deserialisation")
public class MyFormLayoutDeserialisationTest {

    @Autowired
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        objectMapper = objectMapperBuilder.build();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("fails loading seeder json if the keys don't match to object fields")
    void testForcesJsonToMatchFormTemplate(@Value("classpath:bad_nform_layout.json") Resource badLayout) {
        Assertions.assertThrows(UnrecognizedPropertyException.class, () -> objectMapper.readValue(Files.readString(Path.of(badLayout.getFile().getAbsolutePath())), new TypeReference<>() {
        }), "Seeder JSON should have the exact keys and fields declared in the MyFormLayout object");
    }
}
```

Test fails with the message

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Seeder JSON should have the exact keys and fields declared in the MyFormLayout object ==> Expected com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
```

the JSON file

```
[
  {
    "selected": false,
    "disabled": true,
    "app": "blox",
    "foo": "bar",
    "layout": [
      {
        "id": "B-1",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "w": 12,
        "h": 7
      },
      {
        "id": "B-2",
        "x": 13,
        "y": 0,
        "w": 4,
        "h": 4
      },
      {
        "id": "B-3",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 8,
        "w": 12,
        "h": 3
      },
      {
        "id": "B-4",
        "x": 13,
        "y": 5,
        "w": 4,
        "h": 6
      }
    ]
  }
  ...
]
```

`"foo": "bar"` is the unknown property that should have failed deserialisation.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27215864/18121299

Comment: changed the type reference to `new TypeReference<List<MyFormTemplate>>() {}` fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the type reference to new `TypeReference<List<MyFormTemplate>>() {}` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Annotation Effects**: Make sure that annotations like @Jacksonized
   from Lombok are not altering the default behavior of the
   ObjectMapper, particularly concerning the handling of unknown
   properties.
2. **Example of a Global ObjectMapper Bean with Feature Enabled**: You can
   create an ObjectMapper bean with the FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES
   feature enabled and use it throughout your application. Here's how
   to do it in a Spring Boot @Configuration class:

   @Configuration
   public class MyConfiguration {

   ```
       @Bean
       public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
           ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
           objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
           return objectMapper;
       }
   }
   ```
3. **JunitTest isolate:**

   ```
    @Test
    @DisplayName("GIVEN a JSON string with unknown properties WHEN deserialized THEN should throw UnrecognizedPropertyException")
    void debugTest() {
        ObjectMapper localMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        localMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);

        String jsonString = "{\"selected\": false, \"disabled\": true, \"foo\": \"bar\"}";

        Assertions.assertThrows(
            UnrecognizedPropertyException.class,
            () -> localMapper.readValue(jsonString, MyFormLayout.class)
        );
    }
   ```